# Copy contents from a specific cell to an empty column based on number of rows from cells original column

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently faced with the task of inserting a column every second column, replicating the contents of cell into the newly inserted column for the range calculated on the number of rows from where the original value was copied from.

Repeat until all inserted columns have a copied value inserted. See inserted images for example of raw data and transformed data.

Raw Data
[image: Raw Data]

Final Data with contents of third cell copied into range based on cells row count but empty column to left.
[image]

From a code point of view, I have located how to insert the empty column, but calculating the row count and copying the third cell from  B, D, F, to ilastcol into the left columns A, C, E, n for same range eludes me. Plus repeating for every third cell within the number of columns (ilastcol) eludes me. I have looked at row.count to work out the row length.

```
Sub insert_column_after_interval_1()
' Function to insert a column every second column starting from 1.


Dim iLastCol As Integer
    iLastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' same as CTRL+RIGHT ARROW

    For colx = 1 To iLastCol Step 2

        Columns(colx).Insert Shift:=xlToRight

    Next

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more clear, I have no idea what else you want done.

I hope this is what you meant.

```
Sub insert_column_after_interval_1()



Dim iLastCol As Integer
    iLastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For colx = iLastCol To 2 Step -1

        Columns(colx).Insert Shift:=xlToRight

    Next

End Sub
```