# Excel VBA : if for current row a specific cell is not empty, insert specific cells from current row on new row

Tags: excel, vba

SCREENSHOT of desired INPUT & OUTPUT:

https://ibb.co/KFRwXLR

I can't seem to figure this out, i tried to find an example online where new rows are inserted based on cell value of specific column of row-1 , but I did not find any examples.

Example of what I am trying to do:

Code checks each row with data.

IF for current Row : 
cell in column K is empty
result: on new row: output data cells from row, column A to J.

if cell in column K <>empty 
result: on new row: output data cells from row, column A to J.
        on new row: output data cells from row, column A to F , column K to N.

if cell in column K <>empty  AND cell in column O <>empty
result: on new row: output data cells from row, column A to J.
        on new row: output data cells from row, column A to F , column K to N.
        on new row: output data cells from row, column A to F , column O to R.

SCREENSHOT:

https://ibb.co/KFRwXLR

Kind Regards, 
Pieter-Jan

Comment: Search on here for finding the last occupied cell then add 1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have not found an example  by searching what you suggest. Can you provide a link ? KR

Comment: perhaps this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40041918/4961700